# Visio 2016 Font Transparency (Watermark)

Tags: fonts, microsoft-visio, transparency, microsoft-visio-2016

Searching how to make a font translucent, transparent, or look like a watermark in Visio seems to be elusive.  It's common to see the question asked for the word Draft or Confidential, but every guide I found only tells you how to adjust the transparency of the background fill, not of the font itself.  Most will tell you to create another Visio page and set it as the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go into editing mode of your object's text.
- Right-click ... select Font.

  - Here are some things you should *not* select:

    > fill, line, font color, format shape.
- Under the Font tab of the Text properties dialog, there's a section called General.
- There you can select your text color, and there is a transparency slider, complete with text box for the truly finicky.
  [image: Text Properties dialog]

Comment: Over 1k views and only one upvote so far.  Freeloaders XD.